# How do I disable the emoji window but keep the function key active?

Tags: keyboard

Is it possible to completely disable the emoji window on a mac but keep the function key enabled?

The default approach to disabling the emoji window:
[image]

simply does not work.  If I press the globe key twice, it brings up the emoji window again.

If I totally disable the key:
[image]

then it no longer works as a function key.  I test this by holding function and pressing the left or right keyboard arrow keys; with the function key enabled, this behaves like 'home/end' on a normal keyboard.

Comment: After you do the step in the first screenshot, try restarting your Mac and see if the emojis still pop up